# I don't get the values from my firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from my database and my code doesn't return the desired content. It's structure is this:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
firebase.database().ref('proiecte/').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
        console.log(snapshot.val().nume)
});
```

I would expect for my console to return "ROSE" but it returns "undefined". Maybe it helps so I'm mentioning this too: if I run console.log(snapshot.val()) it returns this:

```
{…}
1544696773350: Object { descriere: "Proiectul este dedicat tinerilor!", nume: "ROSE" }
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

So, I'm sure that the database is correctly made just that I'm not using the right format for retrieving data. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong please?

Comment: is `snapshot.val()` one object or an array of objects?

Comment: @Samuel snapshot.val() is an array of objects and I think this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, try the following:

```
firebase.database().ref('proiecte/').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
      let name = childSnapshot.val().nume;
      let desc = childSnapshot.val().descriere;
    });
});
```

Here your snapshot is at node `proiecte`, then you loop using `forEach` and retrieve the data that's under the random id, so you will be able to retrieve `nume` and `descriere`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue!

What I did was to replace ".once('value').then(function(snapshot)" with ".on('child_added', function(snapshot)".